# you’re more than due a vacation - due without for?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives

I do not understand how this sentence makes sense:

> you’re more than due a vacation

Should it not be "due for"? If not, why? What dictionary entry (e.g. Oxford) would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due) as one available for free:

> You’re more than due for a vacation

uses

> 1.2(Of a person) having reached a point where the thing mentioned is required or owed:

Hence:

> You have spend too much time not on vacation, and it is about time you took one.

But

> You’re more than due a vacation

uses

> 1.3(Of a thing) required or owed as a legal or moral obligation:

Hence:

> Your employers owe you a vacation.

This would also correspond with the sense "1. Owed or owing." at [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due#Adjective) which also has an example that is of a more directly comparable form ("He is due four weeks of back pay"). Wiktionary though while often excellent can be dangerous to rely on due to its wiki-based nature, especially when not backed up with quotations.

Comment: Thanks, for a non native speaker, could you rewrite the sentence without the usage of due so I can understand its exact meaning?

Comment: How about the above edit? It's probably a bit strong, but it's a bit clumsy to state without using due. especially since one meaning corresponds with the other so often when we say one the fact that it sounds a bit like saying the other, and they are both true, will be part of the reason we chose *due* rather than another way of saying it.

Comment: If I may ask another clarification: what is the usage in this sentence: The world is due 'a major cyber attack causing widespread harm' before 2025, say experts

Comment: That it's to be expected. Likewise "we're due some rain"; one would expect that this thing would happen by that time (or if a time is not stated, would happen soon).

Comment: I cannot find a suitable entry in the Oxford dictionary :( It confuses me, it says "the baby is due in.. But this is something else, it says "world is due sth in". Another dictionary says "we are dome FOR some rain".

Comment: You're right. It's actually closer to the sense "owed", since it's the world that it says "is due" rather than the attack, but figuratively rather than saying it's deserved as a legal or moral right. (All the senses come from it meaning "owed" originally, with various figurative uses of that becoming fully established as separate meanings).